# Waiting for useState hook increment counter using Promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, use-state

I have a counter which needs to be updated before my DOM is rendered.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
```

I need this to be updated whenever user scrolls, and the function fetchMoreData is called.

So I added it inside Promise and waited until the same has been updated

```
const fetchMoreData = async () => {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setCount(count+1);
      resolve();
    });
    updateNews();
};
```

But this does not seem to be working and count isn't incremented immediately.

How can I resolve the same?

**EDIT :** In the chat, A.mola helped me in solving the issue, so the answer he gave me was according to my code, I am posting the same here.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import NewsItem from "./NewsItem";
import Spinner from "./Spinner";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";

const News = (props) => {
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [totalResults, setTotalResults] = useState(0);

  const capitalizeFirstLetter = (string) => {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
  };

  const updateNews = async () => {
    props.setProgress(10);
    let goToPage = page;
    const url = `newsapi.org/v2/…${props.country}&category=${props.category}&apiKey=${props.apiKey}&page=${goToPage}&pageSize=${props.pageSize}`;
    props.setProgress(30);
    let data = await fetch(url);
    props.setProgress(50);
    let parsedData = await data.json();
    props.setProgress(70);
    if (parsedData) {
      setArticles(articles.concat(parsedData.articles));
      setLoading(false);
      setPage(page);
      setTotalResults(parsedData.totalResults);
    }
    props.setProgress(100);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    updateNews();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  const fetchMoreData = async () => {
    setPage((page) => {
      console.log(page);
      return page + 1;
    });
    console.log(page);
    updateNews();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h3 className="text-center" style={{ marginTop: "4%" }}>
        NewsMonkey - Top {`${capitalizeFirstLetter(props.category)}`} Headlines
      </h3>
      {loading && <Spinner />}
      <InfiniteScroll
        dataLength={articles.length}
        next={fetchMoreData}
        hasMore={articles.length < totalResults}
        loader={<Spinner />}
      >
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            {articles.map((element) => {
              return (
                <div className="col-md-4" key={element.url}>
                  <NewsItem
                    title={
                      element && element.title ? element.title.slice(0, 45) : ""
                    }
                    description={
                      element && element.description
                        ? element.description.slice(0, 50)
                        : ""
                    }
                    imageUrl={element.urlToImage}
                    newsUrl={element.url}
                    author={element.author}
                    date={element.publishedAt}
                    source={element.source.name}
                  />
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </InfiniteScroll>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: The `setState` functions update state asynchronously. Use Functional Updates since you want to use the past value. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: but along with promises ahouldn't they be waited?

Comment: It doesn't return a `Promise` so `await` has no effect on it. Just use the functional update on the `setCount` without the `Promise`

Comment: `const fetchMoreData = async () => {
        setCount(count => count+ 1);
        updateNews();
    };`

tried this but it does not work

Comment: tried to log into console, it gave 1 everytime

Comment: still 1 in console

Comment: Look at this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-shape-58yig?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: yeah, but I can't find the code where u r incrementing this count

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238236/discussion-between-a-mola-and-himanshu-poddar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a.mola for the comprehensive answer, I am updating the answer that you gave me in the chat here.

We are using `useEffect` hook to render our component using the array dependency.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import NewsItem from "./NewsItem";
import Spinner from "./Spinner";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";

const News = ({ country, category, apiKey, pageSize, setProgress }) => {
    const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
    const [totalResults, setTotalResults] = useState(0);

    const capitalizeFirstLetter = (string) => {
        return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const updateNews = async () => {
            setProgress(10);
            let goToPage = page;
            const url = `newsapi.org/v2/…${country}&category=${category}&apiKey=${apiKey}&page=${goToPage}&pageSize=${pageSize}`;
            setProgress(30);
            let data = await fetch(url);
            setProgress(50);
            let parsedData = await data.json();
            setProgress(70);
            if (parsedData) {
                setArticles(articles.concat(parsedData.articles));
                setLoading(false);
                setTotalResults(parsedData.totalResults);
            }
            setProgress(100);
        };

        updateNews();
    }, [page, articles, pageSize, setProgress, apiKey, category, country]);

    const fetchMoreData = () => setPage(page + 1);

    return (
        <>
            <h3 className="text-center" style={{ marginTop: "4%" }}>
                NewsMonkey - Top {`${capitalizeFirstLetter(category)}`} Headlines
            </h3>
            {loading && <Spinner />}
            <InfiniteScroll dataLength={articles.length} next={fetchMoreData} hasMore={articles.length < totalResults} loader={<Spinner />}>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        {articles.map((element) => {
                            return (
                                <div className="col-md-4" key={element.url}>
                                    <NewsItem title={element && element.title ? element.title.slice(0, 45) : ""} description={element && element.description ? element.description.slice(0, 50) : ""} imageUrl={element.urlToImage} newsUrl={element.url} author={element.author} date={element.publishedAt} source={element.source.name} />
                                </div>
                            );
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </InfiniteScroll>
        </>
    );
};
```

Here is the codesandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-shape-58yig?file=/Infinite.tsx:0-2597